# StoreTest Kit Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, beta-testing

I'm following a tutorial regardning submitting your Windows Phone app for beta test. In the tutorial I'm propmt to use the "Store test kit" from the "Projects" menu in Visual Studio. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and the option for "Store Test Kit" isn't there. Has it been replaced?

I'm developing for Windows Phone 8.1 and I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx) provides useful information.

> If you are developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app:
>
> You must install and run Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 Insider Preview.
>
> You must install Windows App Certification Kit version 3.3 or version 10, which is included in the Windows SDK for Windows 8.1.
>
> You must also install the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK for developing phone apps.

Download Certification Kit => [Link](https://dev.windows.com/de-de/develop/app-certification-kit), SDK should be included within Visual Studio

Comment: It says that Insider Preview takes 16 GB what is Insider Preview and why do I need it? I can't afford 16 gb on my hard drive @xmashallax I have Windows Phone 8.1 SDK and App Certification Kit installed

Comment: You don't need the Insider Preview, the kit and the SDK should be enough